# Grepping several lines from Nmap output

Tags: grep, sed, awk, nmap

I apologize in advance as this is a simple question.

So I'm attempting to scan a Class C to identify all mail servers by IP. The vast majority of IPs aren't mail servers. I'm trying to filter out the ones that are.

I've tried the following but they haven't returned what I wanted.

```
nmap -p 25 192.168.15.1-254 | grep report && grep open
```

and

```
nmap -p 192.168.15.1-254 (grep report | grep open)
```

Is there a different utility that I should use? Or is it a problem with my syntax?

Answer (score 4):

It's not clear for me, are you need strings containing only report or open?
If so, use:
`grep` :

```
nmap | grep -E "report|open"
```

`sed` :

```
nmap | sed '/report\|open/!d'
```

if report and open together

`grep` :

```
nmap | grep report | grep open
```

`sed` :

```
nmap | sed '/report.*open\|open.*report/!d'
```

Comment: With actual regex! +1

Answer (score 2):

Rather than post-processing with grep, try passing the `--open` option to Nmap. This will hide all closed or filtered ports. You can use the `-oG` or `-oA` options to output "grepable" results, too. Here's an example that does what I think you're looking for:

```
nmap -p 25 --open -oA smtp-servers-%y%m%d 192.168.15.0/24
```

The results would be in `smtp-servers-20120607.nmap`, `smtp-servers-20120607.gnmap`, and `smtp-servers-20120607.xml`. You can get IP addresses for open SMTP servers like so:

```
awk '/\<25/open/tcp/ {print $2}' smtp-servers-*.gnmap
```

If you really need this all in one pipeline, you could do it like so:

```
nmap -p 25 --open -oG - 192.168.15.0/24 | awk '/\<25/open/tcp/ {print $2}'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a pipe to both `grep` invocations:

```
nmap ... | grep report | grep open
```

Or, since you tagged with `awk`, just informatively:

```
nmap ... | awk '/report/ && /open/'
```

And `sed`:

```
nmap ... | sed '/report/!d;/open/!d'
```

Comment: Your `sed` variant will fail. it will delete both report and open strings, obviously because open doesn't much report and vice versa. Also `grep | grep` and `grep -e -e` are not similar. First one will match only strings containing report and open, second one will much either only report either only open either both together.

Comment: All the results of the grep statements are still kicking back IP addresses that do not have port 25 open. Ideally I'd like the statement only to display IPs with open port 25 nothing else. But your suggestions are a lot closer to my intent. Thanks!

Comment: @rush you're right about `grep -e -e`, but for sed, as I understand, OP wants both report and open on the line, the sed will do that properly.